# How do I detect if stdio.h is included?

Tags: c, stdio

I have a header `foo.h` file that declares a function prototype

```
void foo(FILE *f); 

/* ... Other things that don't depend on FILE ... */
```

among other things.

Now obviously, to use this header, I need to do the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
```

I would like to surround this particular prototype with something like the following:

```
#ifdef _STDIO_H
void foo(FILE *f);
#endif

/* ... Other things that don't depend on FILE ... */
```

so that I can `#include "foo.h"` without worrying about `#include <stdio.h>` in cases where I don't need that particular function.

Is the `#ifdef _STDIO_H` the way to go if I want my code to be portable and standards compliant?

I could find no mention of `_STDIO_H` in the standards document, but I see it is used in a variety of C libraries. Should I rather use something that I know to be defined in `stdio.h`, like `EOF`?

A related question: What do you do for other standard C headers, like `stdlib.h`?

Comment: You can do: `struct FILE;` and not worry about inclusion, or check `#ifdef FILE`.

Comment: Incidentally, you risk greatly confusing your users who happen to include `foo.h` first, then `stdio.h` afterwards.

Comment: Are you looking for cross-platform builds? If yes, https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/ is a suitable project for you. If no, what is your goal with this?

Comment: @perreal: There are lots of things that can go wrong with that. First, `FILE` and `struct FILE` are not the same thing in `C`. Second, I do not believe the standard guarantees the existence of `struct FILE`.

Comment: @wigy I realized as I was typing the question that the most obvious is to just `#include <stdio.h>` and be done with it, but it is just about neatness for me: not including `stdio.h` if I don't need it in a particular source file.

Comment: @Wernsey: If this is really an issue, why not break `foo.h` into `foo-noio.h` and `foo-io.h` or some similar scheme. IMO, I really like my `#include` directives to be commutative and idempotent.

Comment: I don't post this as an answer, because it doesn't do that thing, but you can `#include <stdio.h>` several times without problem.  Thinking that `stdio.h` actually defines macro `_STDIO_H` is a portability error.  You can reach a system where it doesn't actually `#define` it, and fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are part of the C99 (and C11) standards. So every (hosted) standard conforming C implementation have them.

On most practical implementations, they are header files with some [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

<sup>A standard conforming implementation might process `#include <stdio.h>` very specifically, e.g. by using some database. I know no such implementation.</sup>

So simply add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

near the top of your header file, something like

```
// file foo.h
#ifndef FOO_INCLUDED
#define FOO_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
// other includes ...
// ...
// other stuff
#endif /* FOO_INCLUDED */
```

Alternatively, you could not care and *document* that `#include "foo.h"` *requires* a previous `#include <stdio.h>`; any sensible developer using a good-enough C implementation would be able to take care of that.

Actually, I was wrong in my comment on [Alter Mann's deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29117739/841108). It looks like [`stdin` is required to be some macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), and then you might use `#ifdef stdin` ...  `endif` as Alter Mann correctly answered. I believe it is not very readable, and you just want to have `<stdio.h>` included, either by including it yourself in your `foo.h` or by requiring it in your documentation.

Contrarily to C++ standard headers, C standard headers are in practice quite quick to be compiled, so I don't think it is worth to optimize the unusual case when `<stdio.h>`  has *not* been included.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `stdio.h` file (for your compiler) and see whether it has _STDIO_H or similar definition.

Comment: But this is not standard conforming so becomes implementation specific.

Comment: This does not answer my question, because I asked whether there was a standard conforming way to do this, and your solution depends on the vendor of the C library, rather than any standards.

Comment: @Wernsey, that's true, but the **only standard way** to cope with your problem is to `#include <stdio.h>` again.  This way you can assure it has been included (I know this is not the answer to your question, the other one you have already tested, is to let the compiler fail with some error produced by the no-inclusion of this file), as it has for sure some kind of guard that allows you to include any number of times without error.